# How are roles stored in the database?

Tags: user-roles

I know roles are defined http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities but how are they stored in the database? For instance, how is "Super Admin" stored i.e. 'super_admin'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core functions:

- `is_super_admin()`,
- `grant_super_admin()`,
- `revoke_super_admin()`

fetch the super admins data from the `wp_sitemeta` table with:

```
$super_admins = get_site_option( 'site_admins', array( 'admin' ) );
```

It's stored as a serialized array of user logins, for each site, like:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:6:"louiev";}
```

It's possible to override it with the global `$site_admins` array.

On the other hand, the general user roles (*admin*, *editor*, *author*, ...) are stored as serialized arrays, for each user, like:

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

in the `wp_usermeta` table under the `wp_capabilities` meta key  and/or the `wp_{$blog_id}_capabilities` meta keys.

Note that the `wp_` prefix might be different on your install.

Comment: I believe the key is actually `wp_capabilities`?